# Why do people use bouncycastle instead of Java's built in JCE provider? What is the difference?

Tags: java, cryptography

Why do people use bouncycastle instead of Java Cryptography Extension? What is the difference?

Comment: JCE is a standard API that any crypto algorithm can implement to allow for it to be accessible without coding dependencies on the provider. In other words, using the JCE APIs, you can switch ciphers and cipher providers without changing your code (in many cases). BC is a provider which means they implement ciphers that can be accessed through the JCE APIs. If another provider comes along that implements the algorithm you want better than BC or a newer, stronger algorithm, you can switch without changing your code (probably).

Answer (score 89, accepted):

BouncyCastle has many more [cipher suites and algorithms](http://bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) than the [default JCE](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) provided by Sun.

In addition to that, BouncyCastle has lots of utilities for reading arcane formats like PEM and ASN.1 that no sane person would want to rewrite themselves.

Comment: Sun never intended to be an exhaustive provider of ciphers. It's why JCE uses the provider framework which BC supports http://bouncycastle.org/specifications.html#install . Any users of BC would be wise to use it through the JCE APIs when possible.

Answer (score 32):

Bouncy Castle is Australian in origin, and therefore is not subject to the [Export of cryptography from the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_from_the_United_States).

It is useful if you are outside the United States and you need to manage key sizes grater than permitted by such that restriction. In that case you are not permitted to use software from United States for that.

Comment: I wonder how many restrictions that actually remain, anno 2016 ?   As far as I understand there's no longer a restriction on key size as long as you register with US Department of Commerce's Bureau of Industry and Security (BIS), something I guess Oracle is already doing. But the regulations are cryptic (pun intended).

Comment: Ugh, if I am outside of USA I don't need to be permitted anything. The project may need to be permitted to ship something.

Comment: Most of the restrictions in the western world are based on where it's exported to rather than key size these days.  The key size limitation was one of the things relaxed at the end of the '90s.  As for current Australian regulations, it's not quite as lax as this answer implies, but it's not as bad as as the fearmongering of a few years ago was concerned of either (unless you invent a new algorithm and one or two other things.  In general it's covered by the Wassenar Arrangement and the ITAR regulations (via AU DoD).

Comment: An addendum to the above comment and which might indicate what can be done from Australia; I completed the DoD ITAR checks without tripping a single point (all of which were just "call us for clarification" type responses anyway) and so there's no barriers to my FOSS crypto work, though none of it is in Java.  This is because AU concerns are more with new and innovative cryptography developments, not things that are well known everywhere anyway (also the AU DoD definition of "public domain" is **not** the usual copyright one, they use it to mean that it's not classified or restricted).

Answer (score 12):

On server or desktop, I don't see any reason to use BC unless you have to deal with some legacy ciphers or formats not supported by Sun JCE.

However, many JREs don't come with a JCE provider, like on mobile or embedded environments. BC comes handy in such cases.

Comment: On server there definitely is a reason, if your server is using TLS and you care about security (if you don't, why are you using TLS at all?). The cipher suites included with JCE only includes AES in CBC mode, which has a couple of known problems: http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.dk/2013/11/a-roster-of-tls-cipher-suites-weaknesses.html.

Comment: FYI This not true Java8 (From Oracle) at least.